# How to convert to the degree measurement by sf in r?

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm new with `sf` and geographical data. I have a dataset where the geographical information is not measured in terms of degrees. I can not figure out what kind of measurement is used and thus how to transform them into degrees.

As shown by the bounding box, the numbers are too large to be degrees. And `mapview` does not recognize these numbers and draws a wrong map.

```
> map %>% select(iso.a3)

Simple feature collection with 213 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -999 ymin: 4660 xmax: 9851 ymax: 9851
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
   iso.a3                       geometry
1     FRO MULTIPOLYGON (((4046 8611, ...
2     UMI MULTIPOLYGON (((-539 6673, ...
3     USA MULTIPOLYGON (((-349 7098, ...
4     JPN MULTIPOLYGON (((8399 7927, ...
5     SYC MULTIPOLYGON (((5874 6366, ...
6     IND MULTIPOLYGON (((6970 6817, ...
7     FRA MULTIPOLYGON (((2583 7984, ...
8     FSM MULTIPOLYGON (((8905 6704, ...
9     CHN MULTIPOLYGON (((7445 7068, ...
10    -99 MULTIPOLYGON (((1921 6969, ...

> st_crs(map)

Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: WGS 84 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Comment: how did you read in the data / where does it come from? You need to know the original CRS before you can convert it.

Comment: I read the data with `read_sf`. Sorry, I'm not sure about the source of the data and its original CRS.

Comment: I have a feeling that you're not dealing with Longitude and Latitude. It could be something measured in meters. There are a lot of options for projections measured in meters. If you can point to the data source, we may be able to give you more info. If you can figure out the crs, you can use `st_transform()` to convert to longitude and latitude.

Comment: when you use `read_sf()`, where does it point to? is it a file on your computer? If so, where did that file come from?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is by getting the centroid of the sf geometry:

```
sf_object |> 
st_geometry() |> 
  st_centroid() |> 
  unlist() |>  
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!  But I'm afraid I have not made my problem quite clear. The trouble is in the measurement of the location, which is not using the numbers in the interval [-360, 360] or [-90, 90].  Please note, for example,  that in the first row of the geometry column a point is presented by (4046 8611). As I found that `mapview` did not work with this sort of coding, I want to change it into the measure in terms of degrees.

Comment: Try the `sf::st_make_valid()` function on your sf object.